# How to get resolution of app video preview for iPhone 6 (750 x 1334)?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've just created some app video previews for both the iPad and iPhone 6 Plus in iMovie and was able to export these videos to the needed sizes (900 x 1200 for iPad and 1080 x 1920 for iPhone 6 Plus). As a bonus, Apple allows us to use the 1080 x 1920 resolution for 4 inch devices.

That only leaves the iPhone 6 which needs to be 750 x 1334. There is no option to export to this size in iMovie as I don't believe it's a standard size.

I am wondering, how are people producing videos for this resolution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) Download [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr) (open source video transcoder)

2) Open HandBrake, click picture settings in the top right and enter 750 x 1334 for the resolution and close the window.

3) Change the anamorphic setting to none in picture settings (or else it will steal one of your pixels and make it 1333 x 750).

4) Click start in the upper left of the main window and it will save your new video to the desktop.

Edit: Updated to reflect fix mentioned below to prevent losing one pixel on the width (thank you).

Comment: 1333x750 ... it stole one of my pixels

Comment: @quemeful to keep the extra pixel, you need to switch the 'anamorphic' setting to 'none'

Comment: It seems Handbrake cannot scale up, only down. So using this option the original need to be higher res than desired target resolution.

Comment: Handbrake ver:0.10.3(latest as of now), did it one go for 750x1334, default settings worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As @quemeful mention solution above can give you 1333x750 video.
To get strict 1334x750 resolution use 
    anamorphic: none
in picture settings.